# I am trying to download mp3 file from path using php, but instead of downloading its displaying some weird content on page

Tags: php, download, mp3

```
<?php

$fileName = $_GET['file'];
$path = '/directory/contains/mp3/';
$file = $path.$fileName;

if (!file_exists($file)) {
    http_response_code(404);
    die();
}

header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Content-type: audio/mpeg3");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);
//So the browser can display the download progress
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));

readfile($file);
?>
```

The output is like

ID39TPE1SoundHelixTDRC2009TCONElectronic���ϑ�^D�a@k��iC����� l<"f�`znŢ4(.�tN9�q?�]��n���������>K�l�<�� !�@� H�q�z �����w9���������>|��>'�(��`�J�I0e `���bzb�a�d9���Ns�ӞM��� B)�4�@�C�'��>.���tDDB8/��Z%rШp3G�C�|N ��[���s�]�v�����> =hD1*�3�1��3��#Ŏ5���r�Q ���L��*�g�R(\bt��6Wo���mO"�� � ���4��_������"�9�sB|�N ��������t!���+q��x�b�� #Ѩ�~?����@ %\�F�ObsF�+qe�����ȓ�"�D��aR�j�0�a�.���'� �|����zޫ��9���`���~�M"�� �M�e}k���z�d\��ᡱ4"�O����@���q�+��p�O�������� e1[�0�������p1������~?D��IWBx/qx�J�Lcy@dq�\ 'G���"�6Զ�$ebT�it���.�>�u���"QY�Zrs����T��a"��R������Ϛ"5P*a٤��Q������X �>�lh`d!�hƎ����"����~?�����D�a�+Bh�Q^�;���Z��Pa��FI���H��M�-��Bؕ6�];����E��]~�����VD��׹9���y�U�0�M�)U����Qbg��0��C�(��������,�>�lh`d!�.�3�� EE�/@  $�o04��<���Mk��t���n3 ���fX�aվ= ��:�ǤR{J}��F/)O���F+ӰF�� �����>�̘��� �âW��F�d�a�"'�!!����)�bh�Z���#wU�׸}��"�f�x�����{w��tJ�%)�����������a�L/@  $�o04��<���Mk��t���n3 �F+ӰF�� �����>�̘��}#@#0��>Ѯ�"��d���Ha,o7 E�c�4B-J�T������>�ݑh�tԼ�������L:%r��y<�9������vd����J��)����]�7���R�q��D����櫔����LS��ep;�!�?����li8ݔ#��KY&"w�fCt�7\9STj��s�kV�Ί���_^����z�kR��;3*ݶ�������Ǻ�;ji}!@��J��)����]�7���R�q��D����櫔����LS��ep;�!�?����li8�(G��(�&LD�f̆4��n�r���}\��:֭Ý[!ν�����f��jQ��W��fe[�U��[�gs�8��ǫa�����>z@�i�Z *�As$��T�a�!p��L�d�������WϛF����i��R_OaTd�[�ܮ\t),��U��Ͽv9]�=y;�� 8�%9IB�r�T�Ǔn�_�3�*_�c�� k�_�x@�Hّj� .-Y�0��,`0�)���7 g �R5)�ilHfF�&�7��d�7n��,�"����&c������lڥɎX���wdy�33�r���z��������������9���]�����������L'2z��Q��l6'�� a�Y���|N\7��}ϳǙP�U8�3<ě��3�(o'2���I����Q9�o��{��\f��L���U�{�*~��}���%�.�J�����>� ���5�3��IGA��1��q<�0ڟ��ӎ��Q��l6'�� a�Y���|N\7��}ϳǙP�U8�3<ě��3�(o'2���I����Q9�o��{��\f��L����]�8�����͘?�K�]$�7W�}4+��jg��� ��b)�c��y�a�?���$ w� �l!�\��6O��5�"�Vo�;5|V�fr &peI��������gU�=`����Q�}Ll<��=�������jV���[���E��ZO@�5�L~�x#�BU ��|

Comment: [1] Try to wrap the file name with quotes. [2]  Try changing content-type to `audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3`

Comment: Another thing, for security reasons you want to do `$fileName = basename($_GET['file'])`. Otherwise, I can add some `../../` to `file` parameter in the URL and access sensitive files.